# How to run a Brother embroidery machine with "PE - Design Ver.7"?

Tags: wine, brother

I need to use a design program that help me with my work and I cannot make the software functions because the hardware element that my program (software) needs is not recognized.

The software I need to use is "PE - Design version 7" because I have an embroidery machine that functions with the files created with that software. The hardware element that is not recognized is a Card-writer module connected to the computer from USB.

I installed the software using "wine" and I don't know if this is part of the problem because the software is for windows use.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 recently updated from 13.04 and I had the same trouble on the past version of Ubuntu.

I hope someone could help me with this. Also I know my English is not so good, but I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

"PE - Design version 7" is Windows only. Your best bet would be to install virtualbox/vmware, install Windows and then go from there.

You could ask Brother if they might support Linux in the future, but since they don't even support Macs I have a feeling this won't happen in a long time.

Comment: Thank you!!! I will try on virtualbox or vmware. If not, then I will have to reinstall Windows... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AndrésAlanValdovinosVitte I am at the same point having just been giften an older machine. Did you end up getting PE Design to work? How about the Card Reader?